# SQL how to delete rows across tables with same ID

Tags: sql, vb.net

In my tables for SQL, I have many tables each with an ID column I wish to keep incrementing, along with a main name table with an ID which will be the same value as the corresponding IDs in other tables for the relevant information. I wish to be able to make it so that, when I delete a row from the name table with a certain ID, all values across other tables with the same ID get deleted also. The issue appears to be that, if i create foreign key constraints from the name ID on the name table to the other IDs across other tables, it means these tables are no longer allowed to automatically increment.

Comment: You are looking for cascading foreign key relationships.  I would suggest looking up how to do that in the database you are using.  With such relationships, the database does the deletes for you, so the data remains "in synch".

Comment: I found some dodgy workaround where I can set values in the table as variables in my VB program, and use that to compare to all the other table IDs, and if they're the same they delete. Basically the tables are all linked without actually being linked

Comment: Again, as @GordonLinoff mentions, look into referential integrity with cascading updates/deletes even index constraints to avoid orphaned records. You want to link related tables and most *relational* database management systems have facilities for that without needing application layer workarounds.

Comment: Your last sentence is wrong. You should create a constraint that links the PK in the parent table to the FK in the child table. The child table has its own PK, which auto-increments.